# How to print "can't , doesn't , don't , .... " in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to print " We can't find an email matching the information you provided. "

But PHP won't let me. Anyone know how to fix this ?

[image]

`return Redirect::route('account-forgot-password')

```
->with('error','We can't find an email matching the information you provided. You may have entered an email that doesn't exactly match our records. Try again ');`
```

Comment: "Can't" or 'Can\'t'.

Comment: Use double quotes instead of single ones. Not ',but ", or put \ in front of quotes you want to use as quotes.

Comment: You can either use double quotes or a backslash '\' to escape the quotes

Comment: The [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) has a bunch of examples and explanations around the 4 different ways of specifying string literals.

Comment: people should generally read much more in the manuals...this is such a basic question that RTFM (with a link to the article) should be an accepted answer :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the single quotes to doublequotes

```
->with('error',"We can't find an email matching the information you provided. You may have entered an email that doesn't exactly match our records. Try again ");
```

or 
change single quote character with a backslash like ' to \'

```
->with('error','We can\'t find an email matching the information you provided. You may have entered an email that doesn\'t exactly match our records. Try again ');
```

Answer (score 5):

Well you could change the single quotes to doublequotes, so like:

```
with("error","We can't find an email matching the information you provided. You may have entered an email that doesn't exactly match our records. Try again ");
```

Comment: What I find amazing is that even for a simple question such as this, many answer by suggesting escaping the quote. +1 because you're the only smart enough to provide the simplest, cleanest and easiest to read solution.

Comment: For further details see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Answer (score 1):

What's happening every time you type a single quote is you're closing out the string and PHP starts reading the following text as code. You can avoid this by using double quotes to contain the entire string:

```
->with("error","We can't find an email...");
```

or by "escaping" the single quote character with a backslash

```
->with('error','We can\'t find an email...');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the characters like this:

`echo('I don\'t like apples');`

Answer (score 0):

you have to use \' like `with('error','We can\'t find an email matching the information you provided. You may have entered an email that doesn\'t exactly match our records. Try again ');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP HEREDOC syntax, like:

```
$errorMessage = <<<EOD
Example of string with ' and " :)
spanning multiple lines
using heredoc syntax.
EOD;
```

then use as variable in your function:

```
->with('error', $errorMessage);
```